# Issue in creating instance of peeking reader in spring batch job

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-bean

I have Master step

```
@Bean
public Step employeeMasterProfilePhoneStep() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get(Constant.MASTER_PHONE_STEP)
            .partitioner(Constant.PARTITIONER_STEPNAME_WORKERSTEP, employeeProfilePhonePartitioner())
            .listener(employeeProfileStepListener())
            .step(employeeProfilePhoneStep())
            .taskExecutor(employeeProfileTaskExecutor())
            .gridSize(20)
            .build();

}
```

Worker step

```
@Bean
public Step userProfilePhoneStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("userProfilePhoneStep")
            .<UserProfile, UserProfile>chunk(2000)
            .reader(custPhonePeekingReader())
            .processor(employeeProfileProcessor())
            .writer(employeeProfileItemWriter)
            .listener(ItemReaderListener)
            .listener(ChunkListener)
            .build();
}
```

Stepscope on method which creates objects based on number of execution context in Partitioner (In my case I have 3 execution contect)

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public CustPhonePeekingReader custPhonePeekingReader() {
 return  new CustPhonePeekingReader();

}
```

My custPhonePeekingReader() is never invoked from the worker step even though it should have created 3 objects since I have 3 execution context created in partitioner.

But if I change the method name to customerPhonePeekingReader or anything other than "custPhonePeekingReader" worker step able to invoke and create 3 instances of CustPhonePeekingReader. Any issue or conflict in bean name ? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your master step you have:

```
.step(employeeProfilePhoneStep())
```

but the worker step is called `userProfilePhoneStep()`. This is incorrect.

For the reader, since you are using a method call to set the bean here `.reader(custPhonePeekingReader())`, then what you are describing should not happen. You did not share all the code so the issue should be elsewhere.

You can try to inject the reader like this:

```
@Bean
public Step userProfilePhoneStep(CustPhonePeekingReader custPhonePeekingReader) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("userProfilePhoneStep")
            .<UserProfile, UserProfile>chunk(2000)
            .reader(custPhonePeekingReader)
            .processor(employeeProfileProcessor())
            .writer(employeeProfileItemWriter)
            .listener(ItemReaderListener)
            .listener(ChunkListener)
            .build();
}
```

I would do the same for the processor and writer.

Comment: Thanks. added stepscope to peeking reader class 
`@Component \n
  @StepScope \n
public class CustNamePeekingReader implements ItemStreamReader<Profile> {`

In Job
`@Autowired \n

 private CustNamePeekingReader custNamePeekingReader;`

Comment: Separate instances are created correctly now for each partition after the suggested change

Comment: Great to hear that! If the answer helped, please accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.